# Mail attachment text has \0 in front of every Character in c# Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices 2.2

Tags: c#, character-encoding, format, exchangewebservices, attachment

I am using the NuGet Package Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices for C# to read from my mailbox and read text file attachments.

While this usually works, I now have a perticular set of emails where the text content of the attachment is off.

This is my code to access the attachment:

```
EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(service, Mail.Id);
// load attachments
FileAttachment fileAttachment = message.Attachments[0] as FileAttachment;
fileAttachment.Load();
string newSoxAttachment = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(fileAttachment.Content);
```

This is the filename:

```
2018-11_GPM-User-Verification-Report.txt
```

This is what the file should look like (works in editor):

[image]

this is what the string `newSoxAttachment` actually contains:

```
ÿþ=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=
\0M\0O\0N\0T\0H\0L\0Y\0 \0G\0P\0M\0 \0U\0S\0E\0R\0 \0V\0E\0R\0I\0F\0I\0C\0A\0T\0I\0O\0N\0 \0R\0E\0P\0O\0R\0T
\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=

\0R\0E\0P\0O\0R\0T\0 \0R\0U\0N\0 \0I\0D\0:\0 \0R\0I\0D\02\00\01\08\01\02\00\01\00\01\00\01
\0R\0E\0P\0O\0R\0T\0 \0R\0U\0N\0 \0D\0A\0T\0E\0:\0 \00\01\0.\01\02\0.\02\00\01\08
\0D\0A\0T\0A\0 \0F\0O\0R\0 \0M\0O\0N\0T\0H\0:\0 \02\00\01\08\0-\01\01
\0T\0a\0s\0k\0 \0V\0e\0r\0s\0i\0o\0n\0:\0 \02\0.\00

\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=
\0F\0I\0N\0D\0 \0R\0E\0P\0O\0R\0T\0 \0D\0A\0T\0A\0 \0A\0B\0O\0U\0T\0 \0D\0I\0S\0A\0B\0L\0E\0D\0 \0U\0S\0E\0R\0S\0 \0B\0E\0L\0O\0W\0:
\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=\0=
```

Basically a `\0` is placed in front of every single letter. I believe this is an Encoding issue but I dont know which encoding I need. I already tried the UTF series and default

Comment: You are reading UTF-16 encoded text.

Comment: System.Text.encoding dows not provide UTF 16 possibility

Comment: Take a look at the `Encoding.GetEncoding` method. There's also a byte-order-mark (BOM) at the first two bytes.

Comment: @julianbechtold Why would you say/think such a thing? Do you really think that MS forgot about UTF-16? Also, what do you make out of: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.unicode?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @Micha Wiedenmann then try a `System.Text.Encoding.UTF16`. It won't work. not every one knows that instead you have to use `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode`

Comment: `Encoding.Default` is always wrong except when it's exactly right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Code above resembles UTF-16 as Dragonthoughts correctly stated.

However, `System.Text.Encoding.UTF-16`is not available

therefore, use `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode` or `System.Text.Encoding.BigEndianUnicode`

(try out which of both works for you)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to treat UTF-16 as ASCII. Each basic character is 2 bytes wide in UTF-16.

Since the characters that you are looking at have a code-point below 255, they have a leading zero.

Comment: System.Text.Encoding.UTF16 is not available. would System.Text.Encoding.UTF32 also work?

Comment: No, I'm sorry it wouldn't. You need to decode the utf-16 to a string and then, guessing at your output, re-encode it as UTF-8. That will trim down characters with code points below 128 to be as you expect, but still represent the whole unicode range.